# VirtueMart 2.5 Index.php Template

Tags: php, templates, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm looking for a way to remove the product(s)  link in the mod_virtuemart_cart. I want the product name - just no link. I'm stuck on line 34 of the default.php page under mod_virtuemart_cart/tmpl/:

```
 <div class="product_row">
            <span class="quantity"><?php echo  $product['quantity'] ?></span>&nbsp;x&nbsp;<span class="product_name"><?php echo $product['product_name'] <-- RIGHT HERE ?></span>
        </div>
```

Any ideas? Below is an URL to an image to help better show what I'm trying to accomplish.

http://superiordash.com/images/templatehelp.png

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: the image attached is not visible unless you are registered in the vm forum

Comment: No doubt - Linked corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in file JRoot/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/cart.php

on line 1663:
change this:

```
$this->data->products[$i]['product_name'] = JHTML::link($url, $product->product_name);
```

to this:

```
$this->data->products[$i]['product_name'] = $product->product_name;
```

or other method is to use jQuery to remove the link.

Comment: Yup - Thanks! Don't know why there is not a way to edit that mod through templates - but then again, I have a rather soft knowledge with Joomla and PHP.

Comment: FYI - The line to change is now **1692** in VirtueMart 2.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

FYI adding the following code at about line 20 to an override module template file in your template directory:
/templates/(name)/html/mod_virtuemart_cart/default.php

will result in a better manner to avoid breaking in the future:

```
// Remove links from products
foreach ( $data->products as &$product ) {
    $product['product_name']    =   strip_tags( $product['product_name'] );
}
```

Pull the default.php file from your /modules/mod_virtuemart_cart/tmpl folder and copy it to your template/html folder and edit.